# What is the best way of sorting huge collection in Mongodb & Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

so I have a collection of 160k documents. but each request in my application, I only send 50 and it works like this;

```
      const events = await this.eventModel.find(query).limit(50);
```

It works fine, but the collection might not be sorted base on the time of the event. if I do something like this, it takes too much time;

```
      const events = await this.eventModel.sort(someSorting).find(query).limit(50);
```

so what is the way in this situation?

Comment: Did you index the property which you use for sorting? Read more [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes). It can make a sort query of 160k documents go from many minutes to 1 second

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to work around:

***Improve Query:***

```
// Here first find then apply sort
const events = await this.eventModel..find(query).sort(someSorting).limit(50);
```

***Add Index within schema using Mongoose:***

```
const eventsSchema = new Schema({
  // ... other properties
  event: { type: [String], index: true }
});
```